# React-admin will not properly add id to show view url

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am not able to get my show view to work. I am receiving an error that says:

> Element not found

My data within my mongodb for the _id is a string and not an ObjectID. I don't think that is the issue but there are some dashes that are prepended to the beginning of some of the id's in the database. My show component looks like the following:

```
import React from "react";
   import {Show, SimpleShowLayout,DateField, TextField,BooleanField,NumberField,TabbedShowLayout,Tab
   } from "react-admin";
   import { GridTab } from "../../../common/components/layout/Grid/GridTab";
   import { ReferenceGridTab } from "../../../common/components/layout/Grid/ReferenceGridTab";

   export const JssSessionShow = props => (
       <Show title="Session View" {...props}>
         <SimpleShowLayout>
           <TextField source="session" />
           <DateField source="expires" />
           <TextField source="id" />
        </SimpleShowLayout>
   </Show>
 );
```

I don't know how to get my id to be correctly added to the url for my show view. Please someone help me with this.

Comment: Source and actual data needs to be identical. You are using `source="id"`, but you mentioned `_id` as db field.

Comment: I have tried to change ```source="id"``` to ```source="_id"``` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: It's the other way around. You need to send `_id` as `id` in your data.

Comment: How would I do that? I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: You have some kind of API where you get the data. Either directly send an id or use the dataProvider to map the fields.

Comment: We've done that already. The fields are mapped so that _id in mongo is actually id. We are using GraphQL to talk to the mongodb directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. The backend that the dataprovider was using was not talking to the correct source.